RN Expo - FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/50.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
After having fresh setup for React native expo application on my org. provide new Mac M1, I got following issue first time to run RN expo application on emulator
Starting project at /Users/ajit.waghmare/Projects/MWP/my-workplace-native-mvp
env: load .env
env: export EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_VARIANT EXPO_PUBLIC_STORAGE_KEY EXPO_PUBLIC_AZURE_CLIENT_ID EXPO_PUBLIC_AZURE_TENANT_ID EXPO_PUBLIC_AZURE_SCOPES EXPO_PUBLIC_AZURE_ISSUER_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_AZURE_USER_INFO_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_AZURE_LOGOUT_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_CAR_PARK_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_MY_OFFICE_API_ENDPOINT_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_SHAREPOINT_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_AWS_ACCESS_KEY EXPO_PUBLIC_AWS_SECRET_KEY
(node:57717) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Starting Metro Bundler
warning: Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)

**FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/50.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/50.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain**

    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/ajit.waghmare/Projects/MWP/my-workplace-native-mvp/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:104:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:512:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:170:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:90:21)


Environment

OS - MAC M1 Sequoia 15.1.1
Node v23.4.0
npm 10.9.2
Expo 52.0.18
React 18.2.0
React Native 0.73.6

I'm not sure why its happening, do I need to downgrade node/npm or check anything else here?
I tried deleting node_modules, .expo and package-lock.json for 2 times but same message appearing.
There is no internal/external certificate file in project.
I also tried with solution mentioned on below qustion to set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 but no use
npm request failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

One workaround I found on github.com/expo/expo/issues/20940
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm run start

or
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 expo start

which temporarily worked for me, but its not permanent solution..
